# Is there a way to make Java Applets work today?

Tags: java, browser, applet

Recently, I came across with a problem at work.

A person needs to use a web service that mandatorily requires Java Applets to work.
I searched a lot and saw that those were removed from browsers because were insecure. And later on removed from Java itself.

I could not find a way to make it work. Downgraded it to Java 8 and even tried to use what rested from Internet Explorer (Which has Java Scripts enabled on "inetcpl.cpl").

Any suggetions on how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using our [CheerpJ Applet Runner extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/bbmolahhldcbngedljfadjlognfaaein) for Chrome (free for non-commercial use). It is based on CheerpJ, a technology that allows to run unmodified Java applets and applications in the browser in HTML5/JavaScript/WebAssembly.

Full disclosure, I am CTO of Leaning Technologies and lead developer of CheerpJ

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Applet Runner](https://www.japplis.com/applet-runner/). With it, you can run Java Applets (for free) in your IDE (JetBrains, IntelliJ IDEA, NetBeans or Eclipse).
With the pro version, you can run Applets as a standalone application.

Full disclose, I'm the author of Applet Runner.